# Center div and float image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center the footer menu and have an image with `float: right`. But the menu becomes centered within the width that is not occupied by the image.
So is it possible to center the menu in relation to the whole screen or container width?

I've tried to include image in a div and assign `position: relative` to the div and `position: absolute` for the image and adjust the div width to 100% but then my menu is inaccessible. If I change z-index of the image to -1 I can click the menu but the image disappears.

Here is an example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mortalis/pen/WdRoWG).

Comment: I can't see your image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, don't float the image. Instead use abolsute positioning on it, and relative on the footer:

```
img {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
footer {
    width:500px;
    height: 100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8n84d6yp/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Can you post your full code? including HTML and CSS

From what you wrote it seems like you should have two `div`: one for your footer text and another for your image. You should wrap your whole footer with a `footer` for good practice. You can use absolute positioning on your image instead.

```
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px; /* Or whatever % or px value you'd like */
    position: relative;
} /* feel free to assign other values, such as a border, shadow, etc. */

.img {
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Another way you could do this is to create a css id called "footer wrapper" that you can use to wrap text inside a div. This could be used beyond just a footer. A classic wrapper example would look like this:

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: -webkit-calc(800px - (#{$spacing-unit} * 2));
    max-width:         calc(800px - (#{$spacing-unit} * 2));
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: $spacing-unit;
    padding-left: $spacing-unit;
    @extend %clearfix;
}
```

$spacing-unit is a _sass variable you can set as a certain value (in px).